# PHP Indirect modification of overloaded property

Tags: php, class, properties, overloading

i have this simple class:

```
class A
{
    var $children=array();

    function &__get($name)
    {
        if($name==="firstChild")
        {
            if(count($this->children)) $ret=&$this->children[0];
            else $ret=null;
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

By accessing the "firstChild" property it should return its first child by reference or null if there are no children.

```
$a=new A;
$c=&$a->firstChild;
```

Now if the class contains at least one child it works great but if it doesn't (and it should return null) it triggers the error "Indirect modification of overloaded property".

Why does this happen? I'm not trying to modify anything so what is that "Indirect modification"? And why if i remove the reference sign (`$c=$a->firstChild;`) it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use `empty()` instead of `count()`. One reason for that is (quote from manual for `count()`)

> If var is not an array or an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if var is NULL, 0 will be returned.

Also, if you're storing objects in this array, you don't have to use references, since (in PHP 5+) objects are passed reference by default.